# ordering query by grouped, calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In an **MS Access 2010** database, I am trying to design a query that will return results ordered by the ratio of the sums of two grouped fields.  But my attempts so far are resulting in an immediate overflow error, before even the query has had a chance to try running.  **How do I fix the code below so that my resulting query produces results that are ordered by the calculated field?**

Here is the table structure:

```
Table1
    ID
    NAME

Table2
    ID
    SUBSET
    TOT
```

Here is the query that causes the overflow dialog box:

```
SELECT [Table1].[NAME], SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) As SubsetDays, 
    SUM([Table2].[TOT]) As TotalDays,
    ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) As SubsetPercent 
  FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN [Table1] ON [Table2].ID = [Table1].ID 
  GROUP BY [Table1].[NAME] 
  ORDER BY ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) DESC;
```

---

### **EDIT#1**

As per @TonyStark's comment, I tried changing `ORDER BY ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) DESC;` to `ORDER BY 4 DESC;`, but this change still results in the overflow error.  The only way I can get the query to run is to remove the `ORDER BY` clause entirely, which defeats the purpose of this question.

---

### **EDIT#2**

I tried the code suggested in EvDev's answer, but his code also still results in the same overflow error.  There are perhaps 2000 rows in each table, though one of the tables has 250 fields.  The datatypes are text for NAME and number for SUBSET, TOT, and ID.

Comment: have you tried ORDER BY 4 Desc ?

Comment: `Overflow` may be because `Sum([Table2].[TOT])` when grouped by `NAME` is returning a 0 for one of the returned records. Dividing by 0 being impossible. Perhaps do something like `iif(SUM([Table2].[TOT])=0, <some constant value>, ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4))` or something like that... You could also check to see if `SUM(TOT)` is 0 by removing the ORDER BY and checking the results.

Comment: And now that I look at it more closely, I think it's exactly a divided by 0 error. Remove the `ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) As SubsetPercent` from your SELECT and change the order to `ORDER BY totalDays Asc` and look for 0's.

Comment: @JNevill That did it.  If you want to write that up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as the accepted answer and +1.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing up Answer from comments/troubleshooting:

Overflow in Access is often caused by a division by zero error. In your query:

```
SELECT [Table1].[NAME], SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) As SubsetDays, 
    SUM([Table2].[TOT]) As TotalDays,
    ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) As SubsetPercent 
  FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN [Table1] ON [Table2].ID = [Table1].ID 
  GROUP BY [Table1].[NAME] 
  ORDER BY ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) DESC;
```

You twice divide by `SUM([Table2].TOT)`. Once in the `SELECT` clause and once in the `ORDER BY` clause.

You can adjust those formulas to look for a `0` in the denominator before dividing to avoid the overflow error. Something like:

```
iif(SUM([Table2].[TOT])=0, <some constant value>, ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4))
```

The reason that it didn't throw the error when you removed the `ORDER BY` clause is because Access doesn't calculate the results for every single record unless it needs to for display, or for `ORDER BY` or some other pre-aggregation type logic. If you had tried to sort the results after running the query without the `ORDER BY` clause, you would have then received the overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code as is so your problem might be sheer volume of records or something to do with datatypes.  Either way I created an other version of your code using a subquery that may work.

```
SELECT * from 

(select [Table1].[NAME], SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) As SubsetDays, 
SUM([Table2].[TOT]) As TotalDays,
ROUND( (SUM([Table2].[SUBSET]) / SUM([Table2].[TOT]) ) , 4) As SubsetPercent 
FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN [Table1] ON [Table2].ID = [Table1].ID 
GROUP BY [Table1].[NAME] ) 

order by SubsetPercent DESC
```

Comment: Your suggestion still results in the same overflow error.  There are perhaps 2000 rows in each table, though one of the tables has 250 fields.  The datatypes are text for NAME and number for SUBSET, TOT, and ID.

Comment: It's probably something in your data then.  Did you try JNevill suggestions above?